# Can CDI inject remote instances of my Bean?

Tags: dependency-injection, junit, ejb-3.0, cdi, jboss-weld

Can CDI inject EJB references in my remote EJB client?

Actually I've a JUnit test case that runs locally on my system and access a EJB running on a standalone JBoss AS. I'm currently using JNDI to access remote business interface of the bean and testing the same.

I would like to know, If @Inject can help me here injecting my EJB instance directly to my test case so that I could avoid JNDI lookups and still access the EJB?

Answer (score 7):

Not portably.  From the CDI specification:

> The unrestricted set of bean types for
>   a session bean contains all local
>   interfaces of the bean and their
>   superinterfaces. If the session bean
>   has a bean class local view, the
>   unrestricted set of bean types
>   contains the bean class and all
>   superclasses.  In addition,
>   java.lang.Object is a bean type of
>   every session bean.
>
> **Remote interfaces are not included in
>   the set of bean types.**

Comment: What about a non-portable solution? I'm particularly interested if Wildfly has something for that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  I recommend opening a new question and then linking it in the comments here.